# how to automatically launch the rate and review feature in windows-store app on launching the app for 5 times?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows, windows-store

How to set **counter for how any times the app has been opened** and according to that counter we implement rate and review feature.
for-example. if that has been opened for 5 time re perform the desired action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RateMyApp](https://github.com/Microsoft/rate-my-app) for that

Just add the FeedbackOverlay in XAML and customize it any way you like.

```
  <rma:FeedbackOverlay Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       EnableAnimation="True"
                       RatingTitle="RatingTitle"
                       RatingMessage1="Rating Message 1"
                       RatingMessage2="Rating Message 2"
                       RatingYes="Yes"
                       RatingNo="No"
                       FeedbackTitle="FeedbackTitle"
                       FeedbackMessage1="Feedback Message 1"
                       FeedbackYes="Yes"
                       FeedbackNo="No"
                       FeedbackTo="feedback@company.com"
                       FeedbackSubject="Feedback Subject"
                       FeedbackBody="Feedback Body"
                       CompanyName="MyCompany"
                       ApplicationName="MyApplication"
                       FirstCount="5"
                       SecondCount="10"
                       CountDays="False" />
```

Code sample taken [from official documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/rate-my-app/blob/master/Doc/RateMyAppGuide.pdf).

Comment: i got the error "FeedbackOverlay is not supported in a Windows App project". :/